# ARIMA forecasting flat line

Tags: forecasting, arima

I browsed most of the posts with a similar problem but I couldn't solve my problem. I am new to R and I am trying to forecast consumption based on past values. There isn't much data(8 days in a 5 minute interval). A sample is as follows:
[Time and Power consumption sample data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PChf.png)

```
# Libraries required
library(dplyr)
library(tseries)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(forecast)

# Code start
power_use <- read.csv("Power Use.csv")
time_vector <- dmy_hm(power_use$ï..Time)
ac13 = power_use$power.shelly1pm.8CAAB57782C4

# Fill missing data using "Impute" 

  # Find the columns with the missing data
  list_na <- colnames(power_use)[ apply(power_use, 2, anyNA) ]
  list_na
  # Compute the mean of each column in the data while ignoring missing data
  avg_missing <- apply(power_use[,colnames(power_use) %in% list_na],2,mean,na.rm =  TRUE)
  # Replace NA values with the median value computed in the previous step
  power_use_replaced <- power_use %>%
    mutate(ac13_mean_replaced  = ifelse(is.na(ac13), avg_missing[14], ac13))
  sum(is.na(power_use_replaced$power.shelly1pm.8CAAB57782C4))
  sum(is.na(power_use_replaced$ac13_mean_replaced))
  head(power_use_replaced)

# de-trending and de-seasonalizing 
AC13 <- power_use_replaced$ac13_mean_replaced
plot(time_vector,AC13,type= "l")
noSnoT = diff(AC13)
noSnoT
plot1 = plot(time_vector[2:length(time_vector)],noSnoT,type = "l", xlab = "Time", ylab = "Energy in kWh")
# Dickey-Fuller Test 
Stationarity = adf.test(noSnoT, alternative = "stationary")
if (Stationarity$p.value <= 0.01) {
  print("AC13 is a stationary data set")
}

# ACF and PACF(Partial Auto Correlation Factor)
acf(AC13) # The decaying plot shows that AC13 is not stationary
pacf(AC13) 

acf(noSnoT) 
pacf(noSnoT)

# Splitting data into training and validation period 
train_per <- 0.8
limit <- floor(train_per * length(noSnoT))
train_noSnoT <- noSnoT[1:limit]
train_noSnoT
validation_noSnoT <- noSnoT[(limit+1):length(noSnoT)]
validation_noSnoT

arima_noSnoT = arima(train_noSnoT, order=c(0,0,1))
arima_noSnoT
checkresiduals(arima_noSnoT)
forecast_noSnoT = forecast(arima_noSnoT,h=length(validation_noSnoT), level=c(95))
forecast_noSnoT
plot(forecast_noSnoT)
```

Can anyone enlighten me as to how to solve my problem? I am getting a flat line validation period which does not match the data in that time period.

Comment: Changing the order to c(6,0,8) yields a non flat forecast. I had to write a code to determine the best order for this time series. Can someone confirm if that is the right approach?

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is a good approach to search for the right order of arima models, but I would rather recommend using tools like auto.arima which automatically find the best order.

The order should be determined by the forecasting accuracy evaluated with test data and not by the appearance of the curve.
Rob Hyndman said multiple times, that a flat time series forecast might hold better results than one with seasonality and trend in many occasions.

If you want to avoid flat forecasts, I would recommend models like FB prophet or linear_regression from parsnip, as they tend to capture the curves dynamic better.

Comment: Thanks Leonhard. I will try experimenting with FB prophet. I can't use linear regression at the moment since I am doing an auto regressive model.

Comment: For autoregressive forecasting I can also recommend the following solution, which I am using myself: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/modeltime.ensemble/vignettes/recursive-ensembles.html As you are probably new to SO, please consider upvoting, if an answer or comment is helpful, or solved your issue

Comment: Thank you Leonhard. I tried upvoting your comment now because it is helpful but I need a "reputation" before casting a vote